# jpg file transfer using a socket_stream in C

Tags: c, sockets, jpeg

I was wondering if sending a file with a jpg extension through a socket_stream, this automatically makes the transformation of bytes to jpg ? or need to implement some algorithm to transform the lot of bytes to image... Please could somebody explain me the way to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JPEG images are nothing but a bunch of bytes organized according to the JPEG format. A network socket isn't going to organize random bytes into the JPEG format. You can send the bytes that make up a JPEG formatted image across a socket as a binary blob, receive it on the other end, and write it to a file with a `.jpg` extension. An application can interpret this file as a JPEG image based on the extension and try to display it. But you are still responsible for providing a set of bytes that are organized as a JPEG image.